# Please reopen and advise on 'Most accurate programs to find similar music?'?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, vote-to-reopen

I've tried to enlarge upon [Most accurate programs to find similar music?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/13741/7064). Please advise of further improvements or reopen?

Answer (score 3):

With your editing it, the question was automatically placed in our review queue (see my comment on it due to that). I'm personally still a bit concerned about the "most accurate" part, as that would require somebody to "know them all" – but apart from that, it's already specific enough to "be valid" IMHO.

Asking for further improvements which could be made: An example of the expected workflow might be helpful, but I'm not sure if it's really necessary.